# OpenLDAP - ldappasswd failing with "invalid parameter supplied: unable to find callback"

Tags: openldap

I have an OpenLDAP syncrepl replica that has updateRef and chaining configured.  I also have AuthzPolicy and AuthzTo configured and working with everything except ldappasswd (or more importantly pam_ldap).

On the replica, I can use ldapmodify and successfully modify any user's userPassword attribute and it works fine and respects my ppolicy password policies as expected.

I'm able to verify that the proxy authorization works via ldapwhoami.   Also, if I use ldappassword directly on the master with proxy authorization (via -X dn:userdn) everything works fine.

When I run ldappasswd on the replica, I get this:

[ldappasswd - invalid parameter supplied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49OOS.png)

The error message is:

"Result: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
Additional info: SASL(-7): invalid parameter supplied: Unable to find a callback: 32774"

Can anyone seen this error before?   Any suggestions on what to look for?

I can share config/log files but I'd have to obfuscate if I do.

Thanks,
Frank